# Magento2 Admin dashboard chart is broken in my all Projects

Tags: magento2, admin, api, dashboard, chart

Today suddenly my admin dashboard chart is not visible.
Live and Test websites are on different server and suddenly today it's broken.
I have check in log file and found that

> [2019-03-19 05:51:17] main.CRITICAL: Unable to read response, or
> response is empty {"exception":"[object]
> (Zend_Http_Client_Exception(code: 0): Unable to read response, or
> response is empty at
> /vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Http/Client.php:1093)"} []

[image]

> **EDIT**

My problem is suddenly fixed automatically,google chart is enable now

Answer (score 5):

The google api called by magento2 is turned off on March 14, 2019 https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/making_charts

Comment: It was working yesterday

Comment: me too, but from now is turned off.

Comment: this api was deprecated in.... April 2012.

After 7 years Magento still didn't know it?

Comment: It not surprise me, so many bugs to fix, maybe they considerer this issue not high priority. If you want you could open an issue in github or find a fix and share with community.

Comment: it is working now automatically

Comment: maybe the service is not shut down completely and sometimes works

Answer (score 4):

We're experiencing the same issue. It looks like the Google Charts API that powers the chart has recently been turned off, though Magento seem to be aware:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/21599

It may be worth navigating to Configuration > Advanced and setting 'Enable Charts' to 'No'. This will at least prevent the error from filling up the exception.log each time the chart attempts to load.